# what is the eigen matrix block packing data structure?

Tags: block, eigen, convolution, packing

Basically I'm seeking for the data structure of eigen packing of matrix. on eigen convolution eigen packed matrix and after that it perform multiplication. Other optimizer like blas,dnn eigen also used packet convolution but they do something on packet processing. As I run a unet model on eigen and other optimizer . eigen don't have data structure overhead but others have.

Comment: The source code is readily available as eigen is a header only library.  Did you look in there to see how they wrote it?

Comment: Yes . Actually i want to edit eigen convolution. but i can't figure out how they packed bolcks.